# retrieve cookies after redirect

Tags: python, cookies

```
class ...
self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie','user_id = %s'% id_and_hash)
        self.redirect("/app/login")

class ThanksHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if 'user_id' in self.request.cookies:
            self.response.out.write('user_id')
        else:
            self.response.out.write("wrong") // what i am getting
```

and i have this cookie (I saw  in a manager of cookies)

```
name: user_id
content: 30|a9bdc98e952c0e787aaf0e5466809eea71635d38446d30a9f71f2d15e99fa701
```

well, basically the problem is that i can't retrieve the cookie that has been initialized. Any reason for that?

Comment: Why aren't you using [`response.set_cookie`](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies) call? My guess: your Set-Cookie header does not set a "path" so the browser uses the path which responded with the Set-Cookie-header (see [RFC 2109, section 4.3.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2109#section-4.3.1)). If you now redirect to an other path, the browser won't send the cookie because the path does not match. Maybe it works if you change the format-string to `'user_id=%s; Path=/'` (maybe the spaces are the problem)

Comment: @vstm you are correct. Please, add as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When setting the cookie directly using the "Set-Cookie" HTTP-header you have to also take care of the cookie-attributes (depending on how you want to use the cookie).

In this case you set the cookie for example in the path `/app/auth` and then redirect to `/app/login`. If you don't explicit specify the cookie-path the browser assumes `/app/auth` and therefore the cookie is not sent when requesting `/app/login`. This behaviour is specified in the [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) (this is more recent than the one I cited in my comment but now the exact algorithm is included in section 5.1.4).

To set the path (or any other cookie-attribute) you can append a list of semicolon-delimited name=value pairs. In this case you want to set the path to `/` (it could be something different like `/app`):

```
self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie','user_id=%s; Path=/'% id_and_hash)
```

Of course most libraries/frameworks already provide a wrapper for the "Set-Cookie" header. In the case of "webapp2" you can set the cookie with [`response.set_cookie`](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html#setting-cookies):

```
self.response.set_cookie('user_id', id_and_hash)
```

It's automatically setting the path to `/` so you don't have to worry about it (it does escape the values properly too).